# Calculate the monthly average including the date where data is missing

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to calculate the monthly average of some data using SQL query where the data resides in redshift DB.
The data is present in the following format in the table.

```
   s_date   | sales 
------------+-------
 2020-08-04 |    10
 2020-08-05 |    20
   ----     |    --
   ----     |    --
```

The data may not be present for all the date in a month. **If the data is not present for a day, it should be considered as 0.**
Following query using AVG() function "group by" month as gives the average of based on the data on available date.

```
select trunc(date_trunc('MONTH', s_date)::timestamp) as month, avg(sales) from sales group by month;
```

**However it does not consider the data for missing dates as 0**. What should be the right query to calculate the monthly average as expected?

One more expectation is that, for the current month, the average should be calculated based on the data till today. So it should not consider entire month (like 30 or 31 days).

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a calendar table might be the easiest way to go here:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('day', t)::date AS dt
    FROM generate_series('2020-01-01'::timestamp, '2020-12-31'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) t
),
cte AS (
    SELECT t.dt, COALESCE(SUM(s.sales), 0) AS sales
    FROM dates t
    LEFT JOIN sales s ON t.dt = s.s_date
    GROUP BY t.dt
)

SELECT
    LEFT(dt::text, 7) AS ym,
    AVG(sales) AS avg_sales
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    LEFT(dt::text, 7);
```

The logic here is to first generate an intermediate table in the second CTE which has one record for each data in your data set, along with the total sales for that date.  Then, we aggregate by year/month, and report the average sales.

Comment: generate_series() does not work as the data is in redshift. So had to generate the date series in a different way. However the logic given here did work.

Comment: @Paul Lesson learned: don't tag with the wrong database.  The only part which would need to be changed is the dates CTE.  Search for how to create calendar tables in Redshift.

Comment: I have figured it out how to generate dates CTE. Regarding the tag, the intention was to get the logic in either Redshift or in Postgres. If the logic is clear, then I think it is not difficult to implement the same in redshift. Your answer is an example.

Comment: @Paul Just for information, Redshift is based on some fork of an old version of Postgres, hence the reason why most (but not all) of my Postgres answer already was working.

Comment: @Paul . . . You accepted an answer that doesn't actually answer the question.  You might want to revert the tag on this question to Postgres and ask a new question.